# php mysql grouping result

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone can help me this?
i have two tables, they are linked by student_id.
im looking for a more cleaner/single query that can output the sample below,
although i achieved this by inserting another query(with group_concat for the subjects)
inside the while loop query for the section and name.

table_students
student_id, section, name

table_subjects
student_id, subject

now i want the output to be like this.

```
student_id    section    name    subject  
100           A          john    algebra, trigo, geometry  
101           A          peter   trigo, geometry,  
102           B          alice   literature, algebra  
103           B          james   trigo
```

thank you in advance.

by the way, i forgot to give some more details,
in my subjects table, the subjects is per row, like this

```
student_id    subject  
    100       algebra  
    100       tigo  
    100       geometry  
    101       trigo
    101       geometry
    102       literature
and so on.....
```

Comment: Sorry, had to make an edit.  I think that is what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks for all the quick responses..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
stud.section, stud.name, group_concat(subj.subject, '') 
FROM table_students stud 
JOIN table_subjects subj 
ON stud.student_id = subj.student_id 
GROUP BY stud.name
```

Comment: hi JPR, your answer is very well working, i just had to add "as subs" SELECT 
stud.section, stud.name, group_concat(subj.subject, '') as subs
FROM table_students stud,  thanks you.
JOIN table_subjects subj 
ON stud.student_id = subj.student_id 
GROUP BY stud.name

Answer (score 0):

Try this MySQL Query:

```
SELECT stu.section, stu.name, sub.subject 
FROM table_students stu, table_subject sub 
WHERE stu.student_id=sub.student_id 
GROUP BY stu.section
```

Should do exactly what you need. Selects the relevant data by student_id in both tables, then specifies which fields to return. Finally, grouping them by section.